# Rails - Creating pdf which contains graphs which are visible to logged in user only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, graph, wicked-pdf

I need to create a pdf using Rails with the following scenario:

My website displays graphs (pie chart and bar graph) for logged in users. I need to add these graphs into the pdf file which will contain data from the database as well.
Note: For creating the graphs on the website, I am using Google charts.

When I tried creating a simple pdf using WickedPdf.pdf_from_url(), it creates a pdf but the data inside is the entire login page. I need the pdf to contain just the graphs which are visible after login.
Note: I am aware that the above mentioned plugin has a build error. But I have also tried other alternatives, but unable to resolve the issue.

Hence would be great if you guys could share some pointers regarding the same.

Code which generates a pdf with login page:

```
user = User.find(111)
sign_in(:user, user)  #Even though I am trying to sign_in the user, pdf shows login page.
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_url(logged_in_url_pointing_to_a_specific_user)
save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs','filename.pdf')
File.open('filename.pdf', 'wb') do |file|
  file << pdf
end
```

A screenshot of the pdf generated is:
[image]

Comment: first off it'd be good to see some code. second, have you tried rendering with a different "layout", in case the layout has all the extra bits from the login page.

Comment: @jad I have edited my question to contain test code. I have also tried to add user login before calling WickedPdf. But it still creates a pdf of the login page.

Comment: okay, you're much better off using the native "render" routines, rather than creating the pdf from the URL.  it keeps it all in the same program and allows you to use the same permissions: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#basic-usage

Comment: @jad: I would like to create the pdf from the URL itself, hence would prefer a solution using .pdf_from_url(logged_in_url_pointing_to_a_specific_user). 
Request you to let me know if that's possible.

Comment: I don't know for certain, as that's not the way I've used it, but you might have success if you can pass cookies to the URL as you render.  I don't know if this is possible, but others might